# jquery autocomplete - returning and formatting multiple elements

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The amount of tutorials out there describing completely different ways to use jquery/ui autocomplete is staggering.  Its extremely difficult to figure out the right way to do it, why you should do it that way, and how to improve it.

I was able to make it function correctly with only 1 element, but now need more.

For simplicity's sake, I'm just returning 2 elements (group_list.name and group_list.description) from mySQL.  I'd like to somehow display them together through autocomplete! Im hoping this is easy!

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" url="<?php echo base_url() ?>/blurb/main/search" action="welcome/find_group">
    <input type="text" id="find_group" name="find_group" placeholder=" Find Group"></input>
    <input type="image" id="image" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>img/board/icons/add.jpg" id="homeSubmit" value="X"></input>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
$( "#find_group" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
            url: "welcome/search/",
            data: { term: $("#find_group").val()},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
               var resp = $.map(data,function(obj){
                    return obj.name;
               }); 
               response(resp);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1
    });
});
```

PHP:

Controller (welcome/search)

```
    public function search()
    {
        $term = $this->input->post('term', TRUE);
        $this->nav_model->autocomplete($term);
    }
```

model->autocomplete:

```
public function autocomplete($term)
{
    $term = $this->page_model->trimfilter($term);
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT g.name, g.description FROM group_list g
                                WHERE g.name LIKE '".$term."%'
                                GROUP BY g.name
                                LIMIT 0, 5");
    echo json_encode($query->result_array());
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What does the returned JSON look like? What specific issue are you running into when trying to display both name and description?

Comment: the issue, unfortunately, is that i dont know how to diplay both the name and description. :\.  The JSON looks like any encodedjson would look, just with name: 'name' | description: 'description'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ajax's success function try something like this:

```
success: function(data) {
        response($.map(data, function(obj) {
            return {
            label: obj.description,
            value: obj.name,
            id: obj.name
            };
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, what this does is display the description during the autocomplete, then once clicked, it puts the name in the input box.  Getting there..just need to adjust formatting it seems?

Comment: That's right. "label" is what you see in the list, and "value" is what goes to the input box once clicked. Using this: `label: obj.name, value: obj.name + ' ' + obj.description,` you will get the name in the list and "name description" once selected.